# Django web app shows list of items with a wrong ordering only in hosting

Tags: python, nginx, django-models, django-templates, postgresql-9.1

I have built a Django web app on a local virtual environment and then published it in Digitalocean.

In the local version, also in digitalocean's virtual environment, I see items displaying by index, starting from `0`:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
```

It displays in this order in the views, and templates as well.

But whenever I turn off:8000 in hosting and switch to Nginx, I get the results as:

```
['banana', 'orange', 'apple']
```

In all pages I see the first item being iterated and shown as the last element. The weird part is it can't even show the `0` index element's id in views, but appears in the template with `{{ element.id }}`.

Also with the same configuration ([you can look at the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeZ7w.png)) and database, when I activate virtual environment and run the server on:8000 port on hosting, it shows in a correct order. 1, 2, 3 are forloop.counter results, and I should get the items with `52`, `53`, `54` ids, which I order by in its modal as well.

Comment: @Spholt thanks a lot for editing my question, it looks understandable now.